# Array of JSON Object to Java POJO

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

Converting this JSON object as a class in java, how would the mapping be in your POJO Class?

```
{
    "ownerName": "Robert",
    "pets": [
        {
            "name": "Kitty"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rex"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jake"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate `POJO` model using `JSON` or `JSON Schema`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This kind of question is very popular and needs general answer. In case you need generate `POJO` model based on `JSON` or `JSON Schema` use [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Example print screen shows how to use it:
[image]

How to use it:

1. Select target language. `Java` in your case.
2. Select source. `JSON` in your case.
3. Select annotation style. This can be tricky because it depends from library you want to use to serialise/deserialise `JSON`. In case schema is simple do not use annotations (`None` option).
4. Select other optional configuration options like `Include getters and setters`. You can do that in your `IDE` as well.
5. Select `Preview` button. In case schema is big download `ZIP` with generated classes.

For your `JSON` this tool generates:

```
public class Person {

 private String ownerName;
 private List <Pet> pets = null;

 public String getOwnerName() {
  return ownerName;
 }

 public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
  this.ownerName = ownerName;
 }

 public List < Pet > getPets() {
  return pets;
 }

 public void setPets(List < Pet > pets) {
  this.pets = pets;
 }

}

public class Pet {

 private String name;

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
}
```

For `Android Studio` and `Kotlin` read [RIP http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org](https://medium.com/@rameshprasad/rip-http-www-jsonschema2pojo-org-fda47c0a95d0).

Answer (score 4):

In the above json you have `ownerName` as property, `pets` as List of objects

```
public class Response {

  private String ownerName;

  private List<Pet> pets;

  // getters and setters
  }
```

**Pet POJO**

```
public class Pet {

 private String name;

 //getters and setters

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following classes:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String ownerName;
    private List<Pet> pets;
}

public class Pet {
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: if i want to retrieve the value both of them then how i get it