# Convert from json in retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

Can not get data from json . using retrofit
My Json that i get from server:

```
{"pages":[{"id":1},{"id":2}], "warning": ""}
```

retrofit interface to handle requests for getting lesson pages from moodle server

```
@POST("/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json&wstoken=xxxxxxxxxx&wsfunction=mod_lesson_get_pages")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<PagesResponse> getLessonPages (@Field("lessonid") int lessonid);
```

PagesResponse class :

```
public class PagesResponse {
    List<Page> pages;
    ArrayList<Warning> warnings;


    public List<Page> getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(List<Page> pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public ArrayList<Warning> getWarning() {
        return warnings;
    }

    public void setWarning(ArrayList<Warning> warning) {
        this.warnings = warning;
    }
}
```

Page class:

```
public class Page {

    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I expect to get ids from response.body().getPages();

but page ids are 0. I have no problem with using other services.

And when I use Object instead of Page. it works fine.

but I cant get data.

Comment: You define `warnings` as a `ArrayList` but in your json sample it's actually a `String` tpye.

Comment: You may also need to define pages as an `ArrayList` instead of a `List` because it will not know which list implementation to choose from

Comment: Take a look on this question [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo/55249189#55249189) There is an example how to generate `POJO` model which fits given `JSON` payload.