# Deserialize without using @JsonCreator annotation

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have an abstract base class which has over 100 implementations. It's too tedious to add @JsonCreator to all the classes.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?
The parent class has a two-argument constructor.

```java
abstract BaseClass {

    BaseClass(A a, B b) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533093/convert-json-string-to-json-objects/55533405#55533405
Hope this will help.

Comment: Please provide sample JSON and maybe one or two BaseClass implementation. It's not clear what are you trying to achieve