# Convert Json to Terraform map(objects())

Tags: terraform

I have a json file as given below

```
{
   "Domain": {
    "Services": [{
        "service1": [{
            "custid" : "1104",
            "fname" : "ton",
            "lname" : "hatf",
        }],
        "service2": [{
            "custid" : "1105",
            "fname" : "ran",
            "lname" : "ttt",
        }],
        "service3": [{
            "custid" : "1106",
            "fname" : "rin",
            "lname" : "wqg",
        }]
    }]
}
 }
```

Could I use Terraform jsondecode()  function to convert the json to the map of objects as given below

```
variable "Services" {
  type = map(object({
   custid     = string
   fname    = string
   lname = string
   }))
  default = {
   "service1" = {
     custid = "1104",
     fname  = "ton",
     lname  = "hatf",
   },
   "service2" = {
     custid = "1105",
     fname  = "ran",
     lname  = "ttt",
  },
   "service3" = {
     custid = "1106",
     fname  = "rin",
     lname  = "wgg",
  }
}
 }
```

I tried to read it using the below code

```
  locals {
     json_data = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/Domain.json"))
    }
```

But unfortunately I don't know how I could use it to build the above map(objects)

Comment: You can use a class to map your json into class accordingly

Comment: Not sure what is your issue? Did you try using `jsondecode`? What did you get? Any errors?

Comment: You can check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533093/convert-json-string-to-json-objects/55533405#55533405

Comment: @PawanTiwari how i could use it with Terraform

Comment: @Marcin Updated the question with the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Domain.json` is **invalid json**. The valid json is:

```
{
   "Domain": {
    "Services": [{
        "service1": [{
            "custid" : "1104",
            "fname" : "ton",
            "lname" : "hatf"
        }],
        "service2": [{
            "custid" : "1105",
            "fname" : "ran",
            "lname" : "ttt"
        }],
        "service3": [{
            "custid" : "1106",
            "fname" : "rin",
            "lname" : "wqg"
        }]
    }]
}
}
```

Then, your `local` can be:

```
locals {
 services = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/Domain.json"))["Domain"]["Services"]
}
```