# Unable to convert a json containing nested json arrays to an equivalent JAVA class using Gson

Tags: java, json, string, gson

JSON string used:

```
'{"Sensors":[{\"name\":\"BLRB50CM_A\",\"cameraId\":\"Cam10\",\"id\":1,\"resolution\":\"1280 x 720\",\"officeLocation\":\"Offshore Development Center\",\"tags\":\"Entrance Camera, Parking Lot\",\"isActive\":\"true\",\"hls\":\"https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8\",\"rtsp\":\"rtsp://10.66.102.66:32278/mystream/parking_lot\",\"type\":\"sensor\",\"inputs\":[],\"outputs\":[2]}]}'
```

java pojo class:

```
public class ServiceFlowData {

    public ArrayList<Sensor> sensors;
    
    public ArrayList<Sensor> getSensors() {
        return sensors;
    }

    public void setSensors(ArrayList<Sensor> sensors) {
        this.sensors = sensors;
    }
}
```

code used for conversion to java object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ServiceFlowData serviceFlowData = gson.fromJson(jsonString,ServiceFlowData.class);
System.out.println("serviceFlowData"+serviceFlowData.getSensors());
```

iam getting get sensors as null.

what is it iam mising here..?

Comment: You can use this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533093/convert-json-string-to-json-objects/55533405#55533405

Comment: Class must have the same variables as in the JSON that you want to map with it, and they are case-sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

Your json key is **Sensors** and not **sensors**.

**Solution 1**

Try changing

```
public ArrayList<Sensor> sensors;
```

to

```
public ArrayList<Sensor> Sensors;
```

**Solution 2**

You can use [`@SerializedName`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28957285/3094731) annotation to map a json key to a java variable with a different name.

Comment: It's kind of a bad idea of doing it like that. Gson has a special way doing the same preserving the code to the Java code conventions.

Comment: @fluffy Updated the answer for an alternative.