# How to parse and display that code of response Okhttp?

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, gson

[json want to parse and display link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1savdeoNPwRe6scq-TBm3EabWP6z2gdv7/view?usp=sharing)

that Is a response.body of Okhttp and I want parse and display it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Java class that has the same structure as that jsonBody then Using gson library     (add this to gradle implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2') you can simply do this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourCLass yourClass = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), YourCLass .class);
```

Comment: What is the reason of creating `JSONObject` instance if after creation you create `JSON` string again? Why not `gson.fromJson(jresponse.body().string(), YourCLass .class)` directly?

Comment: It's just a habit because most of the times i'm getting jsonObject.getJsonArray("items") something like that so i always carry that arround  and use it but thought might be helpful for a beginner.

Comment: And if a want to pass not all parameters to gson?

Comment: And for display it?

Comment: you have your class you can do what ever you want with it. it dépends where do you want to display it. the simplest method is Toast.maketext(getContext(),yourClass.param1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: and you don't have to create a class that match the json perfectly you just have to create a class with the attributes that you need.

Comment: I want display it in a simple listview.

Comment: check this link https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ it should help you understand more about adapters. and then you just have to pass your list to that adapter.