# Convert a Json Array to Map in java

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am working on a project where I get a `JSON` response from my API using entities and `DTO`

Folowing is the response:

```
return XXXResponseDTO
                .builder()
                .codeTypeList(commonCodeDetailList)
                .build();
```

`commonCodeDetailList` list contains the data from the database. Final output will be

```
{
  "code_type_list": [
    {
      "code_type": "RECEIVING_LIST",
      "code_list": [
        {
          "code": "1",
          "code_name": "NAME"
        },
        {
          "code": "2",
          "code_name": "NAME1"
        }
      ],
      "display_pattern_list": [
        {
          "display_pattern_name": "0",
          "display_code_list": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code_type": "RECEIVING_LIST1",
      "code_list": [
        {
          "code": "1",
          "code_name": "NAME"
        }
      ],
      "display_pattern_list": [
        {
          "display_pattern_name": "0",
          "display_code_list": [
            "1"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to convert this to Map with key-value pairs. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried.

Comment: Use any of the millions of libraries that exist online? GSON, JSON by Alibaba to name a few...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON data to Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo). Take a look on [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), you can do the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(commonCodeDetailList);
Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Map.class);
```

First you need to convert `commonCodeDetailList` into a json string. After that you can convert this json string to map.

Comment: What is `ObjectMapper`? Or in other words: What library are you using?

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is part of the [Jackson Project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Comment: @Vringar I know and I'm asking, because this should be part of the answer.

Comment: In this case I am confused why you didn't just go ahead and edit the answer.

Comment: @Vringar Because I don't have enough reputation to bypass peer review, which quite too often stops me from queuing edits. I did edit now, though.