# Deserialize json with list of nested objects

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I want to deserialize a json into an object which contains a list of other object using jackson-databind.

I am trying to desrialize below json. I have Class class1 and it has a `List<NestedProp>`. Prop2 is a arraylist. `List<NestedProp> prop2`.

Classe Structure
`

````
class Class1 {
  String prop1;
  List<NestedProp> prop2;
  //setters getters
}

class NestedProp {
  String p1;
  String p2;
  //setters getters
}
`

```
  "class1": {
    "prop1": "pp",
    "prop2": [
      {
        "nestedProp": [
          {
            "p1": "127",
            "p2": "1"
          },
          {
            "p1": "128",
            "p2": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
````

```
While deserialisingI get the below exception:

>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `NestedProp` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('127')
 at [Source: (File); line: 59, column: 7] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[1]->Class1["prop2"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])


    List<Class1> testData = objectMapper.readValue(test.json, Class1.class);
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show us the classes. --- *Hint:* Since there are 3 levels of `{}` braces, you would need 3 classes (unless you use `Map`, but that seems unlikely). Assuming `Class1` has fields `prop1` and `prop2`, and `NestedProp` has fields `p1` and `p2`, what class has field `nestedProp`?

Comment: show the `Class1` code

Comment: @Deapool I have added the class structure. There are only 2 levels. prop1 is String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two arrays in your `JSON` payloads. So, you need to create extra `POJO` for it. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Root root = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Root.class);
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}

class Root {

    private Class1 class1;

    //getters, setters, toString
}

class Class1 {

    private String prop1;
    private List<NestedProps> prop2;

    //getters, setters, toString
}

class NestedProps {

    private List<NestedProp> nestedProp;

    //getters, setters, toString
}

class NestedProp {
    private String p1;
    private String p2;

    //getters, setters, toString
}
```

For below `JSON`:

```
{
  "class1": {
    "prop1": "pp",
    "prop2": [
      {
        "nestedProp": [
          {
            "p1": "127",
            "p2": "1"
          },
          {
            "p1": "128",
            "p2": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Above example prints:

```
Root{class1=Class1{prop1='pp', prop2=[NestedProps{nestedProp=[NestedProp{p1='127', p2='1'}, NestedProp{p1='128', p2='2'}]}]}}
```

See also:

- [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo)

Comment: Ziober My actual json contains an Array of class1.

Comment: @Shrikant, so you need to use `List<Class1>` type in that case.

Comment: Ziober But in Class1 there is List< NestedProps > and Jackson is not able to recoginize that NestedProps class

Comment: @Shrikant, you need to post whole `JSON` payload which you have. My example shows how to deal with nested arrays. In case you have an array you need to use `List`, in case of object you need to use `POJO` or `Map`, in case of `JSON` primitive - `Java` primitive. Please take a look on linked question and proposed solution. There is a tool which create `POJO` model based on given `JSON`.

Comment: @Shrikant, I'm glad to hear that. In case my answer was helpful please take a look at [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)