# How to get specific information in a JSON using GSON and Typetoken?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

Sorry if this question is so basic but I am a begginer with Android and Retrofit. I have a request using Retrofit that returns this JSON:

```
  "live": {
    "5da49030d3d97f19383a65d0": {
      "publisher": {
        "app": "live",
        "stream": "5da49030d3d97f19383a65d0",
        "video": {
          "codec": "H264",
          "width": 1080,
          "height": 1920,
          "profile": "Baseline",
          "level": 4,
          "fps": 0
        }
      },
      "subscribers": [
        {
          "app": "live",
          "stream": "5da49030d3d97f19383a65d0",
          "clientId": "TKEDO7M2",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This JSON property `"5da49030d3d97f19383a65d0"` is a variable.
I want to get informations about the subscribers that are watching the live. I created the following classes in an attempt to retrieve the information.

```
public class Live {
    public Subscriber subscriber;

    public static Live getFromJson(String jsonString) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Live.class);
    }

    public String toJsonString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}

public class Subscriber extends BaseEntity {
   public Publisher publisher;


        public static Map<String, Publisher> getFromJson(String jsonString) {
        Type empMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Publisher>>(){}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, empMapType);
    }
}

public class Publisher {
    public String app;
    public String stream;


    public static Live getFromJson(String jsonString) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Live.class);
    }
}
```

The answer to this request is correct. I believe the problem is parsing that is not being done correctly.

Comment: Can you add code for `Live` class?

Comment: @AmrYousef I added the class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo)