# Postcode data from API using JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, api, gson

I am trying to to use the postcodes.io API to work out distance between 2 postcodes. I am at the stage of just pulling the data, confirming the input. So far I have this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;

class PostcodeData {

    private String status;
    private String postcode;
    private Float longitude;
    private Float latitude;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "status: "+ status + "\npostcode: " + postcode + "\nlongitude: " + longitude + "\nlatitude: " + latitude + "";
    }
}

public class GsonReadWebPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner pcFrom = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("From post code: ");
        String pcFromAns = pcFrom.nextLine();

        Scanner pcTo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("To post code: ");
        String pcToAns = pcTo.nextLine();

        String url = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" + pcFromAns + "";

        try (InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
             Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            PostcodeData pcd = gson.fromJson(reader, PostcodeData.class);


            System.out.println(pcd);
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently stuck on retrieving data past the "response". Example response is:

```
{"status":200,"result":{"postcode":"SW1A 2AA","quality":1,"eastings":530047,"northings":179951,"country":"England","nhs_ha":"London","longitude":-0.127695,"latitude":51.50354,"european_electoral_region":"London","primary_care_trust":"Westminster","region":"London","lsoa":"Westminster 018C","msoa":"Westminster 018","incode":"2AA","outcode":"SW1A","parliamentary_constituency":"Cities of London and Westminster","admin_district":"Westminster","parish":"Westminster, unparished area","admin_county":null,"admin_ward":"St James's","ced":null,"ccg":"NHS Central London (Westminster)","nuts":"Westminster","codes":{"admin_district":"E09000033","admin_county":"E99999999","admin_ward":"E05000644","parish":"E43000236","parliamentary_constituency":"E14000639","ccg":"E38000031","ced":"E99999999","nuts":"UKI32"}}}
```

I am not understanding how to deal with the nested JSON. Any pointers would be great, thanks.

Comment: Gson or Jackson can fix your requirement, do you want to pass the JSON to a POJO then I can paste a sample code line for your easy reference or do you want to read the JSON eliment while the response is remaining as a JSON itself ?

Comment: You need to create a `POJO` model which fits your `JSON` or just deserialiser everything as a `Map`. Take a look at: [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo)

Answer (score 0):

Gson supports nested objects, so you can just define a field on your `PostcodeData` class named `result` that has the same fields as the `result` object in the JSON data.  [This article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-nested-objects) has some additional information that might help.