# Mapping nested JSON to a Java POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am having difficulties mapping a nested JSON response to a POJO using Jackson.  At the moment the values in the Users class return as null.

JSON:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "username": "johnSmith123",
        "email": "johnSmith123@gmail.com",
        "birthday": "1989-10-23"
    }
]
}
```

POJO:

```
public class Users {

  @JsonProperty("username")
  public String username;
  @JsonProperty("email")
  public String email;
  @JsonProperty("birthday")
  public String birthday;

}
```

Controller method:

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        accountUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

Users user = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Users.class);
```

How could I go about resolving this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have everything set up correctly with your POJO.  But the JSON you are trying to consume is a collection of objects.  So instead you would want to use: `List<Users> user = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<Users>>(){});`

Comment: Hi, I just tried that but unfortunately got the following error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.package>` out of START_OBJECT token..

Comment: Ahhh I see you are using Jackson for JSON binding.  I would suggest updating to a more current Jakarta EE complaint JSON binding library, such as, Yasson. Using this library you can consume a list using this syntax: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/blob/master/docs/src/docs/user-guide.adoc#mapping-a-generic-collection

Comment: Thanks for your follow up but I ended up creating a wrapped class as an implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Users` `JSON Object` is wrapped in `JSON Array` which is wrapped in root `JSON Object`. You need to use collections types:

```
TypeReference<Map<String, List<Users>>> usersType = new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Users>>>() {};
Map<String, List<Users>> wrappedUsers = mapper.readValue(body, usersType);
List<Users> users = wrappedUsers.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or create wrapper class:

```
class UsersHolder {
    public List<Users> users;

    //getters, setters
}
```

which you can use as:

```
UsersHolder wrappedUsers = mapper.readValue(body, UsersHolder.class);
System.out.println(wrappedUsers.users);
```

See also:

- [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo)
- [Java 8 flatMap example](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-flatmap-example/)

Comment: I added the wrapper class and it worked fine. One more question, if you don't mind... Does it still make sense to use the User class so I can access it like: wrappedUsers.users.get(0).getUsername() or would this be seen as unnecessary?  Thanks

Comment: @user2047296, actually it depends only from you and what do you prefer. I would probably get the user: `Users user = wrappedUsers.getUsers().get(0);` Wrapper class is only used for deserialisation so it should not be pass to other layers of your app.

Comment: That does make sense, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: My Problem sounds very similar to this. I'm not sure what exactly i need to change for my case. Could you please help me with this question  [Nested JSON response from SQL View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66423759/nested-json-response-from-sql-view) ? I'm running out of time :( @MichałZiober