# Generate POJO from JSON-LD or RDF to be used with Jackson or GSON

Tags: java, jackson, rdf, json-ld

How can I generate a POJO from a JSON-LD specification (or RDF), so that I can serialize and deserialize my POJO that conforms to this specification ?

So, my question is how I can generate a POJO from let's say a big specification, so I don´t have to handwrite an error prone POJO myself to be used with Jackson.

As an example, how can I generate (not handwrite) a POJO that can be used with e.g Jackson (or GSON) out of this :

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "name": "Unlimited Ball Bearings Corp.",
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
    "contactType": "Customer service"
  }
}
```

Is that possible ?

Comment: Could you provide the POJO that would correspond to the example JSON-LD you provided? Normally, you'd use Apache Jena to read the JSON-LD into a `Model` object that you can interact with.

Comment: No, I don't have the POJO, because I want to find out how I can generate it out of the JSON-LD example

Comment: Can’t you just treat the JSON-LD as POjO? That’s sort of the whole point. Note, with schema.org, you can use `type` I place of `@type`.

Comment: If you want to do this online, you can try [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

Comment: See [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo)

Answer (score 2):

[Pinto](https://github.com/stardog-union/pinto) was built precisely to be the Jackson for the RDF space. Note it's not integration *with* Jackson (or GSON for that matter), just something that is inspired by those frameworks.

Full disclaimer, I'm the author of Pinto.