# How to read from to json file and create java class

Tags: java, json, gson

My problem seems to be that i can save the object to json, but i can't convert the json to Java, where is my code:

```java
   public class WebCrawlerDAOJSon implements WebCrawlerDAO{
   private static final String fileName = "web.json";
   private String jsonInString;

   public WebCrawlerDAOJSon() {
       jsonInString = "";
   }

   @Override
   public void save(WebCrawler webcrawler) {
       FileWriter writer = null;   
       try {
           Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
           writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
           gson.toJson(webcrawler, writer);
           jsonInString = gson.toJson(webcrawler);
           System.out.println(jsonInString);
           writer.flush();
           writer.close();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(WebCrawlerDAOJSon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
       }

   @Override
   public WebCrawler load() {
       try {
           Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
           Reader br = new FileReader(fileName);
           WebCrawler web = gson.fromJson(br, WebCrawler.class);
           System.out.println(web.toString());
           return web;
       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(WebCrawlerDAOJSon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
       return new WebCrawler();
   }
   }
```

But when i try to save it, it gives me the following error:

> "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 4 column 8 path
>   $.digraph.vertices." (WebCrawler web = gson.fromJson(br, WebCrawler.class))

If im saving it and i read it the same way, why doesn't it work?

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: @Dinnerspy JDK 1.8

Comment: You mean you get the error when loading it from file? How does the `WebCrawler` class look like?

Comment: The WebCrawler is a class with a digraph<V,E> and arraylists

Comment: Can you show `WebCrawler` class and how `JSON` file looks like?

Comment: @MichałZiober i have sent to your email.

Comment: If you can not post your `JSON` take a look at [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo/55249189#55249189) where it is described how to generate `POJO` classes for a `JSON` payload. You need to decouple business logic from `JSON` serialising/deserialising process. Generate classes uses linked page, implement read/write operation and build your model and then pass to a business logic layers where they will be handled.