# I need to test my entity classes using a parse tool to ensure that everything is working

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, objectmapper

I have  given a json format which is like below and I am asked to convert this json format to entity classes.

```
{
"descriptor": {

"reportName": "Shop Drawing Progress Report",
"subLabel": "My Workflow Project",
"columnGroups": [
  { 
    "groupName": "mainData",
    "groupLabel": "",
    "frozen": true,
    "columns": [
      { 
        "field": "identifier",
        "label": "Workflow Prefix",
        "sortable": true,
        "editable": false,
        "dataType": "String"
      }

    ]
    }]
```

I create entity classes from above json string and one of those entity class sample is below

```
public class TabularColumn {

    private String field;
    private String label;
    private boolean sortable;
    private boolean editable;
    private String dataType;

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public boolean isSortable() {
        return sortable;
    }
    public void setSortable(boolean sortable) {
        this.sortable = sortable;
    }
    public boolean isEditable() {
        return editable;
    }
    public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
        this.editable = editable;
    }
    public String getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }
```

I have to test using parseDesciptor tool which is there in my application to make sure my entity classes generated from the json format are correct.How can I do that?
Here is my parseDecriptor tool which I am using in my java application

```
public <T> T parseDescriptor(String json, Class<T> c) throws IOException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.getDeserializationConfig().disable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            mapper.getDeserializationConfig().enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
            T ret = mapper.readValue(json, c);
            if (!(ret instanceof ReportDescriptor)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified class of type "+c.getCanonicalName()+" does not extend ReportDescriptor");
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: You can generate set of classes using web tool [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), take a look at [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo/55249189#55249189). After that invoke `parseDescriptor` method in this way: `parseDescriptor(json, RootClass.class)`. Where `RootClass` is a class with `descriptor` property. `RootClass` in your case must implement/extend `ReportDescriptor` class, so you need to do this manually.

Comment: If you can get the same result by converting your entity classes to JSON string as input JSON string, then I think which means your entity classes worked!